# Probability of drawing m tickets less than k

Tags: probability

A box contains n tickets each bearing one of the numbers from 1 to n exactly once. m tickets are drawn from the box one by one with replacement. The chance that the largest number drawn is not greater than k is ?

Comment: What are the chances of drawing one ticket less than k?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  what is the chance the first ticket drawn is not greater than $k$?  Having drawn that one, what is the chance the second is not greater than $k$?  Keep going.  As you need them all to be less than $k$, you multiply.

Answer (score 0):

To finish off this problem, for each $1\leq x\leq k,$ the probability that the $x$th ticket's number not greater than $k$ is 
$$\frac{k}{n}.$$ 
Since the drawing of each ticket is independent due to replacement, so the probability that the largest number drawn is not greater than $k$ is 
$$\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^m.$$